# Any documents or open-discussions for traffic-editor?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/10/ros-smarter-hospitals-robotics/), Open Robotics has a plan to make a platform-agnostic traffic editor for the community, which is really awesome.

https://github.com/osrf/traffic-editor

I briefly had a look at the repository, but couldn't figure out the overall design of this tool as it seems doesn't exist any document yet. Please let me know if I overlooked something important information.

In my security robot project, I implemented a topological graph generator that takes OGM as an input to automatically construct a traversable node graph, and a graph modifier can annotate nodes type and modify these node connections manually.
So, I'm really happy to contribute to the community by adapting some part of my tools with the open-sourced traffic-editor and then make it public, and also interested in open-discussion for the community's future plans.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336846/any-documents-or-open-discussions-for-traffic-editor?/) by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK. Now some description added in README. https://github.com/osrf/traffic-editor/blob/master/README.md#quick-start

---

Originally posted by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) with karma: 40 on 2019-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-14**:
Seems @morgan mentioned there isn't much on the documentation side at the moment: [“Deterministic” navigation in ROS](https://discourse.ros.org/t/deterministic-navigation-in-ros/11442/2):

> Documentation is currently non-existent, publicly-viewable examples are not there yet, etc., but it’s coming along.

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2019-11-14**:
Hi! Yes, we'll be adding documentation and publicly-viewable examples / tutorials to the repo.